# what is the difference in these react hook statements?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between these two? Are they the same? **Is there any idea related to the pointer?** Please help thanks! (I could not find any related topics, and this is not related to the destructuring assignment. Please don't close my post)

```
const items = this.state.items <br>
const {items} = this.state
```

Comment: These are equivalent statements and have nothing to do with hooks - they are simply two examples of assignment in ES6.

Comment: "this is not related to the destructuring assignment" — You're asking what the difference between code that uses a destructuring assignment and code which does exactly the same thing without using a destructuring assignment is!!

Answer (score 0):

The first is regular variable assignment

```
const items = this.state.items;
```

The seconds is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const { items } = this.state;
```

> The **destructuring assignment** syntax is a JavaScript expression that
> makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
> objects, into distinct variables.

IMO the only significant difference between the two is the amount of code you write. Destructuring assignment is handy when you need to unpack several object properties.

Compare

```
const propA = this.state.propA;
const propB = this.state.propB;
const propB = this.state.propC;
```

versus

```
const { propA, propB, propC } = this.state;
```